# How to change the hours in a dataset from 01-24 to 00-23 in R?

Tags: datetime, r

I have an annual hourly data set like the one below. The hours are from 01 to 24.

```
 Lines <- "Date,Outdoor,Indoor
 01/01  01:00:00,24.5,21.3
 01/01  02:00:00,24.3,21.1
 01/01  03:00:00,24.1,21.1
 01/01  04:00:00,24.1,20.9
 01/01  05:00:00,25.,21.
 01/01  06:00:00,26.,21.
 01/01  07:00:00,26.6,20.3
 01/01  08:00:00,28.,21.
 01/01  09:00:00,28.9,21.5
 01/01  10:00:00,29.4,22.1
 01/01  11:00:00,30.,22.
 01/01  12:00:00,29.,23.
 01/01  13:00:00,28.4,22.9
 01/01  14:00:00,27.8,22.7
 01/01  15:00:00,27.3,22.3
 01/01  16:00:00,27.,22.
 01/01  17:00:00,26.,21.
 01/01  18:00:00,26.,21.
 01/01  19:00:00,26.3,21.4
 01/01  20:00:00,26.,21.
 01/01  21:00:00,25.9,21.1
 01/01  22:00:00,25.8,21.3
 01/01  23:00:00,25.6,21.4
 01/01  24:00:00,25.5,21.5
 01/02  01:00:00,25.4,21.6
 01/02  02:00:00,25.3,21.8"
```

How to change the data so that the hours become 00 to 23, consistent with %H datetime format in R? Note that "01/01  24:00:00" is actuall "01/02  00:00:00", so not only the 24 is changed to 00, but the date needs to be increased by one day.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function using basic R.  This is hacked together pretty quick, it could be improved in functionality, but you get the drift. x should be a character input, and format gives the date format.

The function extracts the dates and the times from the character vector, finds out which dates need adjusting and uses the fact that the Date class is numeric. Then `gsub` translates 24: to 00: and everything is pasted together again :

```
convert.date <- function(x,format="%m/%d"){
  newDate <- Date <- as.Date(x,format=format) 
  times <- gsub(".*?(\\d+:\\d+:*\\d*)","\\1",x) 

  id <- grepl("^24:",times) 
  newDate[id] <- Date[id]+1 
  times <- gsub("^24:","00:",times) 

  paste(as.character(newDate,format),times)
}
```

Which gives :

```
> convert.date(Data$Date)
 [1] " 01/01  01:00:00" " 01/01  02:00:00" " 01/01  03:00:00" " 01/01  04:00:00" 
   " 01/01  05:00:00" " 01/01  06:00:00" " 01/01  07:00:00" " 01/01  08:00:00"
 [9] " 01/01  09:00:00" " 01/01  10:00:00" " 01/01  11:00:00" " 01/01  12:00:00" 
   " 01/01  13:00:00" " 01/01  14:00:00" " 01/01  15:00:00" " 01/01  16:00:00"
[17] " 01/01  17:00:00" " 01/01  18:00:00" " 01/01  19:00:00" " 01/01  20:00:00" 
   " 01/01  21:00:00" " 01/01  22:00:00" " 01/01  23:00:00" " 01/02  00:00:00"
[25] " 01/02  01:00:00" " 01/02  02:00:00"
```

From here, you can carry on with the rest.

Answer (score 1):

1) If what is meant by mapping 01-24 to 00-23 is that 01 is mapped to 00, 02 is mapped to 01, etc. then here is a solution; otherwise see 2) below.

The `gsubfn` function in the gsubfn package can pick out strings and apply a function to them replacing the match with the output of the function.  We read the Lines in and then match a space, two characters and a colon replacing the two characters with a number one less.  Finally we re-read it:

```
library(gsubfn)
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
L2 <- gsubfn(" (..):", ~ sprintf(" %02d:", as.numeric(..1)-1), L) 
DF <- read.csv(textConnection(L2), as.is = TRUE)
DF$Date <- as.POSIXct(DF$Date, format = "%m/%d  %H:%M:%S")
```

Thus the last bit of the result is:

```
> tail(DF)
               Date Outdoor Indoor
21  01/01  20:00:00    25.9   21.1
22  01/01  21:00:00    25.8   21.3
23  01/01  22:00:00    25.6   21.4
24  01/01  23:00:00    25.5   21.5
25  01/02  00:00:00    25.4   21.6
26  01/02  01:00:00    25.3   21.8
```

2) If what is meant by mapping 01-24 to 00-23 is that 01-23 get mapped to themelves and 24 gets mapped to 00 of the next day then calculate `DF` as shown above and then do this:

```
DF$Date <- DF$Date + 3600
```

so that the last bit of the result is:

```
> tail(DF)
                  Date Outdoor Indoor
21 2011-01-01 21:00:00    25.9   21.1
22 2011-01-01 22:00:00    25.8   21.3
23 2011-01-01 23:00:00    25.6   21.4
24 2011-01-02 00:00:00    25.5   21.5
25 2011-01-02 01:00:00    25.4   21.6
26 2011-01-02 02:00:00    25.3   21.8
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as it substracts 1 from _all_ times. That is not the point, your output is not consistent with the original frame.

Comment: @J,  If that is what is meant then I have added a second answer which is the same as the first except for the last line.